# Can't remotely login to a SQL Server database using sqlcmd

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd, invoke-sqlcmd

I am trying to connect to a remote database using `sqlcmd`. I have tried something like this

```
sqlcmd -U <ComputerName>\Administrator -P adminpassword -S *.*.*.* -d mydatabase
```

But this is causing an error:

> Failed to Login failed for user '\Administrator'

If I log onto the server where my database and run the command, it won't let me log in, either. But if I go into my SQL Server database and create a SQL Server user and run the same command with those details, I can log in.

But what I want to do is log in via the Administrator user from a different machine. Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You can't specify Windows credentials as connection parameters. Use could use the `RUNAS` tool to run `SQLCMD` as a different user, but that will require a domain user. You need to run the command locally on the server to impersonate a local user other than the one logged in. It's a lot easier to connect to using SQL authentication if you're not logged in as the desired user.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's a lot easier to log in using SQL Server Authentication. To run an application as a different user it's as simple as holding shift and right clicking the application, then selected Run as Different user. Then you just log in as that user. The OP, however, seems to be implying that they are using local credentials, rather than that of a Domain. Are you in a Workgroup?

Comment: The workgroup on all our machines is 'WorkGroup', My machine is not part of a domain when I see the systerm properties pop up. Its true I am entering local credentials, but they are the credentials I would use when I connect via remote desktop.

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/02febadd-3a81-4544-814c-ede23dd1220a/login-as-windows-authentication-using-sqlcmd?forum=transactsql

Comment: I am now part of a domain but I notice in the Security/Logins of SQLStudio my domain user isnt here, do I need to create him here as well?

Comment: @YaugenVlasau I tried running that with my domain user however it tells me I have the unknown username or wrong password. But my credentials are correct as I am able to log into my vm with them

Comment: Please try to connect to your SQL Server from your PC using SQL Management Studio with SQL Server credentials. In case of success look for the mistakes in your command line, in case of failure exam your SQL Server security settings, firewalls and the SQL Server Service user

Comment: @YaugenVlasau My credentials are correct but every time I run runas as described on that page ,it dosent run. Instead it out puts a string as "RUNSAS USEAGE:"  followed by example of how to run runas. Is that information incomplete, is there supposed to be commans around some part of command, like if my user name is AdminDomain\Administrator whats the exact command you would run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Windows credentials you should use `-E`:

```
sqlcmd -E -S *.*.*.* -d mydatabase
```

Comment: If you have no domain, there are only 2 options: or you use SQL Server login and NOT Windows login, or your local account <ComputerName>\Administrator should exists on the computer hosting SQL Server, with the same password

Comment: Yes I can use <ComputerName>\Administrator while I'm on the same machine, this is using my windows credential . But I want to use sqlcmd from a different machine using those windows credentials. Do you think this is not possible?

Comment: >>>But I want to use sqlcmd from a different machine using those windows credentials<<< I already said how to do this. Suppose your SQL Server is on the computer pc1 and you are on pc2, then if two pc are not in the same domain the only way to make work Windows Authentication is to create the SAME user with the SAME password on these 2 pc. Create Windows account TEST on both pc with the SAME password. Then, when you connect to pc1, you are pc2\TEST, but you'll be able to connect if pc1\TEST has the same password

Comment: This worked for me. My issue was 1 machine was part of the domain and the other wasn't. Its strange though because I was looking at the mssql driver for javascript and I could see it was using TDS and I was surprised it wasn't using sqlcmd to create the connection but Im starting to think these are actually 2 different things.